# How to apply multiparameter to ssrs report filter

Tags: reporting-services

I have a master that can be filtered using 4 different parameters. I used a iif statement to join all the parameters to filter the report.

The problem I am now having is when more than one paramater is selected, it tends to return values for the first parameter rather than for all
My paramter expression is as follows:

expression

```
 iif(IsNothing(Parameters!Div.Value)=0,Parameters!Div.Value
,iif(isnothing(Parameters!St.Value)=0,Parameters!St.Value
,iif(isnothing(Parameters!Sp.Value)=0,Parameters!Sp.Value
,Parameters!Hc.Value)))
```

values

```
=iif(IsNothing(Parameters!Div.Value)=0,Parameters!Div.Value
,iif(isnothing(Parameters!St.Value)=0,Parameters!St.Value
,iif(isnothing(Parameters!Sp.Value)=0,Parameters!Sp.Value
,Parameters!Hc.Value)))
```

Any help will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
=IIF(NOT ISNOTHING(Parameters!Div.Value), Parameters!Div.Value,
 IIF(NOT ISNOTHING(Parameters!St.Value), Parameters!St.Value,
 IIF(NOT ISNOTHING(Parameters!Sp.Value), Parameters!Sp.Value,
 Parameters!Hc.Value)))
```

Do you only want to check for one value?

I usually check each parameter separately so it uses all of them at once. Though there may be a situation where your theory is what you want.

If you want to evaluate all the parameters, just add them to the **FILTER** of the dataset, table, or group. Choose your field in the **Expression** and the **Parameter** in the **Value**.

[image]

Comment: I want the report to be filtered based on the parameters selected. Currently, it only returns values for the first parameter even if more than one parameter is selected.

Comment: I added the part to add filters.